# Printing debug message in c++ builder 2010

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

I always use Breakpoint to debug my project source code...
Really don't know how to print debug message in c++ builder 2010!!
How to do it !!!

Comment: Are you looking for something other than `printf()`?

Comment: I am looking for printing debug values in a window named output ... remember printing debug message in output window ! As we did in Visualbasic `Debug.print(var1)` and debug window popped out showing your var1 value!

Comment: In Netbeans(using Java lang) we use `System.out.println('I am in output window');`

Comment: Look at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Embarcadero_Debuggers then

Answer (score 7):

You can use following WinAPI function: `OutputDebugString("I am a debug message")`.
Also, you will need to look into debugger options and see if 'Output Messages' option is enabled.

To exclude debug messaging code from release application, you can use following macros.

```cpp
#ifndef _DEBUG 
#define DEBUG_MESSAGE //   
#endif  
#ifdef _DEBUG  
#define DEBUG_MESSAGE(msg) OutputDebugString("msg") 
#endif
```

and then use `DEBUG_MESSAGE("I am a debug message")` in your code.

Comment: To add to this, such debug messages will appear in the IDE's Event Log if you are running inside the debugger.  If you are not, then you can use SysInternal's DebugView utility to receive and display the messages.

Comment: Hi Remy! Thanks that you are here! As you've got what I wanted, I downloaded DebugView from this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647, so how can I use it???

Comment: Just run it. It will automatically intercept all calls to OutputDebugString() (and a few others) and display the text messages inits own window. You can then apply filtering if you want to see only your messages and not messages from other apps.